# CloudFormation Response Object Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I've got a CloudFormation Lambda Backed Custom Resource ,
Lambda function in public subnets but when I check the cloudWatch logs shown it below

Log-Message#1

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cloudformation-custom-resource-response-eucentral1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

Log-Message#2

```
Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

How I can handle this problem , my cloudformation is shown as below .

```
 Resources:
 HelloWorld: #Custom Resource
Type: Custom::HelloWorld
Properties:
  ServiceToken:
    Fn::GetAtt:
    - TestFunction #Reference to Function to be run
    - Arn #ARN of the function to be run
  Input1:
    Ref: Message
 TestFunction: #Lambda Function
 Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
 Properties:
  Code:
    S3Bucket:
      Ref: S3Bucket
    S3Key:
      Ref: S3Key
  Handler:
    Fn::Join:
    - ''
    - - Ref: ModuleName
      - ".lambda_handler"
  Role:
    Fn::GetAtt:
    - LambdaExecutionRole
    - Arn
  VpcConfig:
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref SecurityGroup
    SubnetIds:
      - Fn::Select: [ 0, !Ref PublicSubnet1 ]
      - Fn::Select: [ 0, !Ref PublicSubnet2 ]
  Runtime: python2.7
  Timeout: '30'
   LambdaExecutionRole: #IAM Role for Custom Resource
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service:
        - lambda.amazonaws.com
      Action:
      - sts:AssumeRole
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
  - PolicyName: root
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - logs:CreateLogGroup
        - logs:CreateLogStream
        - logs:PutLogEvents
        Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
        - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
        - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface

        Resource: "*"

   SecurityGroup:
   Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
   Properties:
    GroupName: "sec_group_name"
    GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

My subnets routing table associated with InternetGateway, but it giving CloudFormationResponse object error , How I can solve this connection problem .

Help ! Thanks :))

Comment: I don't have the exact solution, but this might be helpful https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/custom-resource-helper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your public subnet does not have a `NAT gateway` or `NAT instance` attached to it (`InternetGateway` alone is not enogh). As per [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-internet), this is required. If your functions does not need general internet access but access to AWS resources, you should consider `VPC Endpoints`. They are cheaper, but not sure if available for all resources.

Comment: I've created VPC Endpoint and attached it to the LambdaVPC , now I'm getting Forbidden error probably I will attach new role to lambda to access S3 bucket . this will fix this . Thanks :)